# How to unescape non-ascii string in python3?

Tags: python

I want to unescape string like `ЙЙあ\\nあЙЙ` and get as the result`ЙЙあ\nあЙЙ`

I tried often recommended unicode_escape, but it doesn't work as it it doesn't handle anything but latin1.

```
>>> "ЙЙあ\\nあЙЙ".encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")          
'Ð\x99Ð\x99ã\x81\x82\nã\x81\x82Ð\x99Ð\x99'
>>> "ЙЙあ\\nあЙЙ".encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")[0]  == "Й"
False
```

Is there a good way other than to manually scan for sequences like `'\\'+'n'`  ?

Comment: Not really an answer to this question, but idk if you thought about that: You could try using `replace` function. Not sure if this can help you somehow, as it's still based on sequence-scan

Comment: @AlexanderSantos the problem is replace replaces one substring at a time. slash can be both prefix (\n) and suffix (\\) . If you replace \n  first, it will treat suffixes as prefixes and replace what it shouldn't ('\\\\n' -- n should stay untouched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to unescape the string but in case the string is unknown e.g. coming from a user input this is not recommended. Instead use `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast
string = "ЙЙあ\\nあЙЙ"
print(ast.literal_eval(f"\"{string}\""))
```

EDIT: this gives an error if the string contains a speech mark so you might also want to add something along the lines of:

```py
string = string.replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

EDIT: this still gives an error in some cases with combinations of backslashes and speech marks. The solution is to evaluate the string in triple quotes, replacing only the triple quotes in the string and leaving the first one untouched. Here is the code:

```py
import ast
string = '\\"'
string = string.replace(
  "\"\"\"", "\"\"\\\""
  )
print(
  ast.literal_eval(
    f"\"\"\"{string}\"\"\""
    )
  )
```

Comment: This won't work for string='\\"' -- quotation mark will get replaced

Comment: Ok I've found a solution just editing answer now